# changing Mysql to PDO

Tags: php, pdo, echo, session-variables

i am trying to create a shopping using PDO. So far i have done it the older ways and i have been trying for the past 6 days to do this in PDO. Please someone help. How will i do that it PDO

```
dbconnect();
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE ID='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["Name"];
            $price = $row["Cost"];
            $details = $row["Description"];
        }
```

Comment: Try to read the official PDO Documentation and pay attention to the examples. The only drastic change you'll have to do is the way you use the params on the MySQL queries.

Comment: Are you saying you want us to rewrite the code to use PDO for you?

Comment: no explosion i just want to know how to write from the $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");

BUT including the dbconnect();

Comment: I have edited it to show the session i am i having problem doing

Comment: What is `dbconnect()`?

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way and it work. Thanks for all your help everyone

```
$total_cart_items = count($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
dbconnect();
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
$item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE pid=:id");
$stmt->bindParam('id',$item_id);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$product_name = $row["Name"];
$price = $row["Cost"];
$details = $row["Description"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, your current code is quite inefficient. Instead of running several queries, run only one to get all items

```
dbconnect();
if($_SESSION["cart_array"]) { 
    // that's quite tricky part. 
    // have to create a string of placeholders like  ?,?,?
    $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) - 1) . '?';
    // the rest is quite simple:
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Hair_category WHERE Hair_ID= IN($in)";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    $data = $stm->fetchAll();
}
```

Now you have all the items in `$data` array and can iterate it somewhere else (in a template probably)

Proper code for dbconnect() you can see in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Answer (score -1):

Guessing that your dbconnect() function contains the code to create a connection to the database.  Here's how to set up a good PDO connection:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You can read docs on the MySQL format for $dsn here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Then the other parts of your code would be something like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
    $item_id = $each_item["item_id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Hair_category WHERE Hair_ID=:item_id LIMIT 1");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(":item_id"=>$item_id));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $product_name = $row["Name"];
        $price = $row["Start_Cost"];
        $details = $row["Brief_Description"];
    }
}
```

If this causes any error, it will throw an exception, since I set that attribute right after the connection was created.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: please explain why you think this answer is wrong or inappropriate.  Maybe I can improve it.